# Viewpager Relex Circle indicator Color

Tags: android, android-studio, viewpagerindicator

The default color of the viewpager indicator is white.
In relex viewpager indicator in github,
it doesn't include on how to change the color of the indicator.
Is it possible?

```
  <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <me.relex.circleindicator.CircleIndicator
                android:id="@+id/pagerIndicator"
                app:ci_width="10dp"
                app:ci_height="10dp"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="36dp"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp" />
        </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: ask this on library thread

Answer (score 24):

```
    <me.relex.circleindicator.CircleIndicator
        android:id="@+id/pagerIndicator"
        app:ci_width="10dp"
        app:ci_height="10dp"
        app:ci_drawable="@drawable/circleindicator_round"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="36dp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp" />
```

I Dont Care What Padding or Margin You Do

but create a drawable XML File and Add these codes

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="@color/colorAccent"/>
    <corners android:radius="10dp"/>
  </shape>
```

Call it what ever you want
But use

```
`app:ci_drawable="@drawable/circleindicator_round"`
```

worked for me

Comment: perfect. Thanks :)

Answer (score 5):

**From the github page: Under properties**

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <me.relex.circleindicator.CircleIndicator
            android:id="@+id/pagerIndicator"
            app:ci_width="10dp"
            app:ci_height="10dp"
            app:ci_drawable="your drawable defining the color"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="36dp"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```